# Spring not allowing me to autowire my class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have search for a similar question but cant find anything regarding this issue.

This is my Controller class

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
 public class AdminController {


 @Autowired
 private AuthenticationServicesImpls check;

 public AuthenticationServicesImpls getCheck() {
    return check;
 }

public void setCheck(AuthenticationServicesImpls check) {
    this.check = check;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public ModelAndView adminLogin(HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
    return new ModelAndView("adminlogin");

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/authentication")
public ModelAndView validateAdmin(HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "userid", required = false) String username,
        @RequestParam(value = "password", required = false) String password){
    System.out.print(username); 
    System.out.print(password); 



      if(check.validateAdminUser(username, password)){
            return new ModelAndView("adminlogin");
      } else
      {
            return new ModelAndView("error/errorlogin");
      }



     }

   }
```

This is my service interface

```
package online.services;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;



@Repository
   public interface AuthenticationServices {


public boolean isLoggedIn();
public int login();
public int logout();
public boolean validateUser();

}
```

This is my DOE class implementation I Have just used on method only for testing

```
 package online.deo;

   import java.util.List;

   import org.hibernate.Query;
   import org.hibernate.Session;
   import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
   import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import online.model.UserDetail;
    import online.services.AuthenticationServices;

    @Transactional
    @Repository
    @Component
    public class AuthenticationServicesImpls implements AuthenticationServices {

       AuthenticationServicesImpls(){}
      @Autowired
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;




     public boolean validateUser() {

          return false;
     }
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public boolean validateAdminUser(String userID, String password) {
        System.out.print("this is session facoty class"+ sessionFactory.toString());
        System.out.print(userID);   
        System.out.print(password);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println(session);
        Query query = session.createQuery("from user_detail");

        System.out.println(query.list());
        List<UserDetail> user = query.list();

        if (user != null) {
            for (UserDetail us : user) {

                System.out.println(us.getUser_id());

                 if (us.getUser_username().equals(userID)) {
                    if (us.getUser_password().equals(password)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                     return false;
                }
            }

        }
           return false;
         }

         }
```

This is my POJO Class

```
package online.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_detail")
public class UserDetail {
@Id
private int user_id;

@Column(name = "user_first_name")
private String user_first_name;

@Column(name = "user_last_name")
private String user_last_name;

@Column(name = "user_emailid")
private String user_emailid;

@Column(name = "user_mobileno")
private long user_mobileno;

@Column(name = "user_username")
private String user_username;

 @Column(name = "user_password")
private String user_password;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role user_role;

 public int getUser_id() {
     return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getUser_first_name() {
    return user_first_name;
}

public void setUser_first_name(String user_first_name) {
    this.user_first_name = user_first_name;
}

public String getUser_last_name() {
    return user_last_name;
}

public void setUser_last_name(String user_last_name) {
    this.user_last_name = user_last_name;
}

public String getUser_emailid() {
    return user_emailid;
}

public void setUser_emailid(String user_emailid) {
    this.user_emailid = user_emailid;
}

public long getUser_mobileno() {
    return user_mobileno;
}

public void setUser_mobileno(long user_mobileno) {
    this.user_mobileno = user_mobileno;
}

public String getUser_username() {
    return user_username;
}

public void setUser_username(String user_username) {
    this.user_username = user_username;
}

public String getUser_password() {
    return user_password;
}

public void setUser_password(String user_password) {
    this.user_password = user_password;
}

public Role getUser_role() {
    return user_role;
}

public void setUser_role(Role user_role) {
    this.user_role = user_role;
}

}
```

This is my servlet-servlet.xml file

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
      xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     

              enter code here`http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans- 3.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema  /context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/sche/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd"> 

   <context:component-scan base-package="online" />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

   <context:annotation-config />
   <mvc:annotation-driven/> 
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
     <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

        <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" 
        p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Shopping" p:username="root"
        p:password="123456" />

     <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

   <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="check" class="online.deo.AuthenticationServicesImpls" />
    </beans>
```

This is my error stack

```
 by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:    private online.deo.AuthenticationServicesImpls online.controller.AdminController.check; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set online.deo.AuthenticationServicesImpls field online.controller.AdminController.check to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set online.deo.AuthenticationServicesImpls field online.controller.AdminController.check to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    ... 37 more

Sep 04, 2014 5:43:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet SpringDispatcher
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set online.deo.AuthenticationServicesImpls field online.controller.AdminController.check to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not getting why my application is not getting autowired.

Comment: Your service class is being proxied. Change `AdminController` to use the interface `AuthenticationServices` instead of the concrete type `AuthenticationServicesImpls`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default, Spring uses standard java interface-based proxies.  Which means your Spring managed beans must implement interfaces Spring is managing.

If you want to proxy based on classes, you can update the following annotation in your Application Config (I believe this also requires the CGLIB jar):

note the 'proxyTargetClass = true':

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Comment: Hey My friends I have done searching by reading @Mostfoolish and thanks man. I found this I am sharing with you which will helpful to all of you.
    1. what are the functionality provided by the cglib to spring framework ?
    2. what are the functionality provided by the asm to spring framework ?
    3. Difference between cglib and asm ?

Comment: So Spring does a lot of Proxying. Most of the time this is done via DynamicProxy in the JDK at runtime creates a proxy based on the classes interfaces. If you class doesn't implement any interfaces it can't create a proxy. But CGLib can create on the fly proxies by extending the class it is going to proxy.

For ASM, this does byte code weaving/instrumentation at runtime.

Comment: So these instrumentation and proxies are to add functionality to your code without you having to write that code in your code. Either by decoration/proxy or byte code instrucmentation of that code into your class.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
 @Autowired
 private AuthenticationServicesImpls check;

 public AuthenticationServicesImpls getCheck() {
    return check;
 }

public void setCheck(AuthenticationServicesImpls check) {
    this.check = check;
}
```

To:

```
@Autowired
 private AuthenticationServices check;

 public AuthenticationServices getCheck() {
    return check;
 }

public void setCheck(AuthenticationServices check) {
    this.check = check;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Hey the suggestion work. Please help me know what I was doing work with and example.Please and I am getting other error "user_detail is not mapped [from user_detail]" I dont I have mapped it properly but I think the Spring is not getting the hibernate.cfg file.Please me know my mistake.

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: user_detail is not mapped [from user_detail]
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:180)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElemen

Comment: Hey I got it What I am doing wrong I was writing wring (from table name) insist of ( from class name) thanks for helping me but please help me with my first question.Why we do use inferface and not implemented class when we do autowired, thanks @Jens

Comment: So if you Autowiering an Interface you can use many implementations with it, without changing the class wich have the Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your xml file and try to run again.

```
    <jpa:repositories base-package="your.repository.base.package.path"/>
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Till now What I have learned about Spring and Spring MVC. When you enable annotation in your project and you set your base package using 
    <context:component-scan base-package="online" /
The Spring will look inside you base package for /@Controller /@Configuration and /@Repository  to create Bean in runtime .
I dont know Why you need
 <jpa:repostories bas-package="yout.repository.base.package.path"/>
Please put some light on this.